logitech ghub can not run old script from LGS
I been using this script for LGS ( Logitech gaming software) and it was working well all the time. but then I have to replaced my old mouse g502 to G502x which only support by G HUB.
now when I run this script on G HUB, it doesn't work anymore,  in console when i left click nothing happen and show in console but when I right click I'm getting this message event = MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED, arg = 2  and i believe it should show up arg= 1 when i left click.
I've added an image to show the trouble that I get when I run the script using the Logitech mouse g502x on g HUB.
I've also add another function on the top of the script "function math.pow(x,y) return x^y end" because I had similar error before like this one Attempt to call nil value, when run on g hub
am fairly new to Lua and don't really know the mechanics. so I really ask for you help, thank you guys
enter image description here
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
---- key bind ----
local scarl_key = nil
local ump9_key = nil
local hold_breath_key = "lshift"
local m416_key = 11
local set_off_key = 10
local akm_key = nil
local m16a4_key = nil
local uzi_key = nil

---- control_key ----

local control_key = "lctrl" 

---- can use "lalt", "ralt", "alt"  "lshift", "rshift", "shift"  "lctrl", "rctrl", "ctrl"

local ignore_key = "lalt" --- ignore key

--- fastloot setting---
--- Press controlkey and and ignore_key and click Left mouse button ---
--- "lctrl" + "lalt" + mousebutton

local control_key = "lctrl" 
local fastloot = false ---if you don't need it, you can close it by true to false.
local move = 40 ----1920*1080

---- only can use "numlock", "capslock", "scrolllock"

local full_mode_key = "numlock"   ---numlock lamp on,recoil is full_mode."numlock" 
local mode_switch_key = "capslock" 
local lighton_key = "scrolllock"  ---start script,scrolllock l
--- Your Sensitivity in Game amp will be on.close script ,scrolllock lamp will be off.


local vertical_sensitivity = 1 --- default is 0.7
local target_sensitivity = 38 --- default is 50.0
local scope_sensitivity = 38 --- default is 50.0
local scope4x_sensitivity = 38 --- default is 50.0

-- you can close these by true to false

local hold_breath_mode = false
local full_mode = false

---- Obfs setting
-- local obfs_mode = false
local obfs_mode = false
local interval_ratio = 0.75
local random_seed = 1

local auto_reloading = false

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------        Recoil Table        ------------------------------
---------------- You can fix the value here ------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- recoil times
--- if the Recoil compensation is Large or small,You can modify the value of all_recoil_Times or recoil_table{times}
local all_recoil_times = 1

local recoil_table = {}

recoil_table["akm"] = {
    basic={56,41,42,46,48, 58,58.5,62,64,67, 68,71,70,74.4,77, 74},
    basictimes = 1.04,
    full={56,41,42,46,48, 58,58.5,64,68,68, 70,71,70,74.4,77, 74},
    fulltimes = 1.04*0.75,
    quadruple={56,41,42,46,48, 58,58.5,64,68,68, 70,71,70,74.4,77, 74},
    quadrupletimes = 4*1.04,
    fullof4x={56,41,42,46,48, 58,58.5,64,68,68, 70,71,70,74.4,77, 74},
    fullof4xtimes = 4*1.04*0.75,
    speed = 100,
    maxbullets = 40,
    holdbreathtimes = 1.25,
    fullholdbreathtimes = 1.25, 
}

recoil_table["m416"] = {
    basic={44,44,45,46,49,50,51,51,55,55,55,58,61,61,63,63,64,64,64,62,63,62,63,62,63,62,62,62,62,62},
    basictimes = 1.27,
    full={44,44,45,46,49,50,51,51,55,55,55,58,61,61,63,63,64,64,64,62,63,62,63,62,63,62,62,62,62,62},
    fulltimes = 1.08*0.75,  
    quadruple={44,44,45,46,49,50,51,51,55,55,55,58,61,61,63,63,64,64,64,62,63,62,63,62,63,62,62,62,62,62},
    quadrupletimes = 3*1.08*0.9,
    fullof4x={44,44,45,46,49,50,51,51,55,55,55,58,61,61,63,63,64,64,64,62,63,62,63,62,63,62,62,62,62,62},
    fullof4xtimes =3*1.01*0.55,
    speed = 86,
    maxbullets = 40,
    holdbreathtimes = 1.25,
    fullholdbreathtimes = 1.25, 
}

recoil_table["scarl"] = {
    basic={41,33,33,36,41, 40,46,47,45.6,46.5, 47.5,48.5,49.2,52.2,53.1, 53},   
    basictimes = 1.50,
    full={41,30,33,36,41, 40,46,47,45.6,46.5, 47.5,46.5,49.2,52.2,53.1, 53},
    fulltimes = 1.08*0.75,  
    quadruple={41,30,33,36,41, 40,46,47,45.6,46.5, 47.5,46.5,49.2,52.2,53.1, 53},
    quadrupletimes = 4*1.08*0.9,
    fullof4x={41,30,33,36,41, 40,46,47,45.6,46.5, 47.5,46.5,49.2,52.2,53.1, 53},
    fullof4xtimes = 3*1.00*0.55,
    speed = 94,
    maxbullets = 40,
    holdbreathtimes = 1.25,
    fullholdbreathtimes = 1.25, 
}

recoil_table["ump9"] = {
    basic={30,31,32,34,37, 35,35,36,42,38, 39,42,42,41,41, 41,41,42,42,42, 43,40,41,43,40, 40,40,41,42},
    basictimes = 1,
    full={30,31,32,34,37, 35,35,36,42,38, 39,42,42,41,41, 41,41,42,44,42, 43,40,41,44,40, 40,41,42,43},
    fulltimes = 0.75*0.9,
    quadruple={30,31,32,34,37, 35,35,36,42,38, 39,42,42,41,41, 41,41,42,44,42, 43,40,41,44,40, 40,41,42,43},
    quadrupletimes = 4*1*0.97,
    fullof4x={30,31,32,34,37, 35,35,36,42,38, 39,42,42,41,41, 41,41,42,44,42, 43,40,41,44,40, 40,41,42,43},
    fullof4xtimes = 4*0.75,
    speed = 92,
    maxbullets = 40,
    holdbreathtimes = 1.25,
    fullholdbreathtimes = 1.25, 
}

recoil_table["uzi"] = { 
    basic={8.5,8.5,9,9,9,10.5,10.5,10.5,12,13,13,14.5,15.5,16,17.5,18.5,19,19.5,19,19.5,19,19,19.5,20},
    basictimes = 2,
    full={4.8,4.8,5,5,5,6,6,6,6.2,6.8,6.8,7.6,7.6,7.9,8.2,8.2,8.2,8.7,8.7,9,9.5,9.5,9.6,9.6},
    fulltimes = 2,
    quadruple={8.5,8.5,9,9,9,10.5,10.5,10.5,12,13,13,14.5,15.5,16,17.5,18.5,19,19.5,19,19.5,19,19,19.5,20},
    quadrupletimes = 2,
    fullof4x={4.8,4.8,5,5,5,6,6,6,6.2,6.8,6.8,7.6,7.6,7.9,8.2,8.2,8.2,8.7,8.7,9,9.5,9.5,9.6,9.6},
    fullof4xtimes = 2,
    speed = 48,
    maxbullets = 35,
    holdbreathtimes = 1.25,
    fullholdbreathtimes = 1.25, 
}

recoil_table["m16a4"] = {
    basic={42.3,31.2,32.4,42.3,50.4, 54.1,62.1,60,62.5,65.5, 63,62.1,64.4,64.4,65.25,63.9},
    basictimes = 1.23,
    full={42.3,31.2,32.4,42.3,50.4,54.1,62.1,60,62.5,65.5,63,62.1,64.4,64.4,65.25,63.9},
    fulltimes = 1.23*0.77,
    quadruple={42.3,31.2,32.4,42.3,50.4,54.1,62.1,60,62.5,65.5,63,62.1,64.4,64.4,65.25,63.9},
    quadrupletimes = 1.23*4,
    fullof4x={42.3,31.2,32.4,42.3,50.4,54.1,62.1,60,62.5,65.5,63,62.1,64.4,64.4,65.25,63.9},
    fullof4xtimes = 4*1.23*0.75,
    speed = 80,
    maxbullets = 40,
    clickspeed = 40,
    holdbreathtimes = 1.25,
    fullholdbreathtimes = 1.25, 
}

recoil_table["none"] = {
    basic={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    basictimes = 1,
    full={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    fulltimes = 1,
    quadruple={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    quadrupletimes = 1,
    fullof4x={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    fullof4xtimes = 1,
    speed = 30,
    maxbullets = 40,
    clickspeed = 40,
    holdbreathtimes = 1.25,
    fullholdbreathtimes = 1.25, 
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------          Function          ------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------



function convert_sens(unconvertedSens) 
    return 0.002 * math.pow(10, unconvertedSens / 50)
end

function calc_sens_scale(sensitivity)
    return convert_sens(sensitivity)/convert_sens(50)
end

local target_scale = calc_sens_scale(target_sensitivity)
local scope_scale = calc_sens_scale(scope_sensitivity)
local scope4x_scale = calc_sens_scale(scope4x_sensitivity)

function recoil_mode()
    if not IsKeyLockOn(mode_switch_key) then
        if IsKeyLockOn(full_mode_key) and full_mode then
           return "full";
    else
           return "basic";
        end
    end 
    
    if IsKeyLockOn(mode_switch_key) then
        if IsKeyLockOn(full_mode_key) and full_mode then
           return "fullof4x"
    else
           return "quadruple"
        end 
    end     
end
           
function recoil_value(_weapon,_duration)
    local _mode = recoil_mode()
    local step = (math.floor(_duration/recoil_table[_weapon]["speed"])) + 1
    if step > #recoil_table[_weapon][_mode] then
        step = #recoil_table[_weapon][_mode]
    end

    local weapon_recoil = recoil_table[_weapon][_mode][step]
    local weapon_speed = recoil_table[_weapon]["speed"]
    local weapon_clickspeed = recoil_table[_weapon]["clickspeed"]
    local weapon_maxbullets = recoil_table[_weapon]["maxbullets"]
    local weapon_basictimes = recoil_table[_weapon]["basictimes"]
    local weapon_fulltimes = recoil_table[_weapon]["fulltimes"]
    local weapon_quadrupletimes = recoil_table[_weapon]["quadrupletimes"]
    local weapon_fullof4xtimes = recoil_table[_weapon]["fullof4xtimes"]
    local weapon_holdbreathtimes = recoil_table[_weapon]["holdbreathtimes"]
    local weapon_fullofholdbreathtimes = recoil_table[_weapon]["fullholdbreathtimes"]
    local weapon_intervals = weapon_speed    
    local weapon_clicktime = weapon_clickspeed
    local weapon_bullets = weapon_maxbullets 

    if obfs_mode then
        local coefficient = interval_ratio * ( 1 + random_seed * math.random())
        weapon_intervals = math.floor(coefficient  * weapon_speed) 
    end
    -- OutputLogMessage("weapon_intervals = %s\n", weapon_intervals)

    recoil_recovery = weapon_recoil
    recoil_times = all_recoil_times * 0.7 / vertical_sensitivity 

    if recoil_mode() == "basic" and not IsModifierPressed(hold_breath_key) then
    recoil_recovery = recoil_recovery * recoil_times * weapon_basictimes
    end
    if recoil_mode() == "basic" and hold_breath_mode and IsModifierPressed(hold_breath_key) then
    recoil_recovery = recoil_recovery * weapon_holdbreathtimes * recoil_times * weapon_basictimes
    end

    if recoil_mode() == "full" and not IsModifierPressed(hold_breath_key) then
    recoil_recovery = recoil_recovery * recoil_times * weapon_fulltimes
    end
    if recoil_mode() == "full" and hold_breath_mode and IsModifierPressed(hold_breath_key) then
    recoil_recovery = recoil_recovery * weapon_fullofholdbreathtimes * recoil_times * weapon_fulltimes
    end

    if recoil_mode() == "quadruple" then
    recoil_recovery = recoil_recovery * recoil_times * weapon_quadrupletimes
    end
    
    if recoil_mode() == "fullof4x" then
    recoil_recovery = recoil_recovery * recoil_times * weapon_fullof4xtimes
    end

    -- issues/3
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(2) then
        recoil_recovery = recoil_recovery / target_scale
    elseif recoil_mode() == "basic" then
        recoil_recovery = recoil_recovery / scope_scale 
    elseif recoil_mode() == "full" then
        recoil_recovery = recoil_recovery / scope_scale
    elseif recoil_mode() == "quadruple" then
        recoil_recovery = recoil_recovery / scope4x_scale
    elseif recoil_mode() == "fullof4x" then
        recoil_recovery = recoil_recovery / scope4x_scale
    end

    return weapon_intervals,recoil_recovery,weapon_clicktime,weapon_bullets
end

function light_off()
    if IsKeyLockOn(lighton_key) then
        PressAndReleaseKey(control_key)
        PressAndReleaseKey(lighton_key)
    end 
end
function light_on()
    if not IsKeyLockOn(lighton_key) then
        PressAndReleaseKey(control_key)
        PressAndReleaseKey(lighton_key)
    end
end

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------          OnEvent          ------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------


function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
        Fire = false
        current_weapon = "none"
        shoot_duration = 0.0
        if IsKeyLockOn(lighton_key) then
        PressAndReleaseKey(lighton_key)
        elseif IsKeyLockOn(full_mode_key) then
        PressAndReleaseKey(full_mode_key)
        elseif IsKeyLockOn(mode_switch_key) then
        PressAndReleaseKey(mode_switch_key)
        end
    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    end

    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == set_off_key) 
    or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == set_off_gkey) then
        current_weapon = "none" light_off()
    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == akm_key)
    or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == akm_gkey) then
        current_weapon = "akm" light_on()
    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == m16a4_key)
    or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == m16a4_gkey) then
        current_weapon = "m16a4" light_on()
    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == m416_key)
    or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == m416_gkey) then
        current_weapon = "m416" light_on()
    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == ump9_key)
    or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == ump9_gkey) then
        current_weapon = "ump9" light_on()
    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == uzi_key)
    or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == uzi_gkey) then
        current_weapon = "uzi" light_on()
    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == scarl_key)
    or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == scarl_gkey) then
        current_weapon = "scarl" light_on()
    elseif (event == "M_RELEASED" and arg == 3 and Fire) then
        local intervals,recovery,clicktime,bullets = recoil_value(current_weapon,shoot_duration)
        if shoot_duration % clicktime == 0 then
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
        end 
        MoveMouseRelative(0, recovery / 10)
        Sleep(intervals/10)
        shoot_duration = shoot_duration + (intervals/10)
        if auto_reloading then
            if shoot_duration > (intervals * bullets) + 100 then
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            PressAndReleaseKey("r")
            Sleep(200)
            Fire = false
            end
        end
        if not Fire then
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
        elseif Fire then
            SetMKeyState(3)
        end

    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
        -- button 1 : Shoot
        if ((current_weapon == "none") or IsModifierPressed(ignore_key)) then
            PressMouseButton(1)
            repeat
                Sleep(30)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        elseif(current_weapon == "m16a4") then
            Fire = true
            SetMKeyState(3)
        else
            repeat
            local intervals,recovery,clicktime,bullets = recoil_value(current_weapon,shoot_duration)
            MoveMouseRelative(0, recovery /10 )
            Sleep(intervals/10)
            shoot_duration = shoot_duration + (intervals/10)
            if auto_reloading then
               if shoot_duration > (intervals * bullets) + 100 then
               ReleaseMouseButton(1)
               PressAndReleaseKey("r")
               Sleep(200)
               end
            end
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1) then
        Fire = false
        shoot_duration = 0.0
    end

    while (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsModifierPressed(control_key) and IsModifierPressed(ignore_key) and fastloot) do
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
        PressMouseButton(1)
        for i = 0, 14 do
        MoveMouseRelative(move, 0)
        Sleep(2)
        end
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
        for i = 0, 14 do
        MoveMouseRelative(-move, 0)
        Sleep(2)
        end
        Sleep(10)          
    end

end

i tried run the script with old version of g hub, still doesn't work.
i tried delete the top newest function, it came back to the previous pow error "Attempt to call nil value"
